# EF Core Audit Trail when using Update or Attach

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 7.0, and have implemented Audit Trail with the below code, by overriding SaveChangesAsync().

Currently, to update an Entity, we first need to Find By Id, which requires a round trip to the database to load the Entity first, then changing a field and making another round trip to the database to Save.

```
var parent = await context.Users.FindAsync(10);
parent.EmailAddress = "test@test.com";
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Resulting Audit Trail**

- Old Values: "johndoe@test.com"
- New Values: "test@test.com"

***Question***: ***Is it possible to update an Entity without first Finding it, and still generate an Audit Trail?***

I tried context.Update, context.Attach, and context.ExecuteUpdate.

With context.Update(Parent), it marks the entire Parent as EntityState.Modified, causing a large Audit Trail as it thinks all fields were modified. Same with Attach. ExecuteUpdate does not use SaveChangesAsync at all, which is where I implement my Audit trail.

```
var parent = await context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == 9);
parent.EmailAddress = "test@test.com";
context.Update(parent);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Resulting Audit Trail**

- Old Values: "john","doe","21","johndoe@test.com"
- New Values: "john","doe","21","test@test.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you expect EF to generate an audit trail (old -> new) to be generated if EF doesn't first fetch the entity to update it? The first method is the approach I recommend using, though I typically use the `Single`/`SingleOrDefault`/`First`/`FirstOrDefault` methods rather than `Find`. The trouble with `Find` is that you cannot eager load related entities, where with `Single`/`First`... you can.

The added consideration with the pattern of reading a row to edit, then updating it is asserting you are performing a valid update, particularly in web applications and public facing web applications. For instance in many cases a user will only ever update particular rows that belong to them or that they are authorized to update.  If a user might do something like update a delivery address, it should ensure that the order being updated is theirs, and in a state that can be updated, which means reading that data. Accepting parameters including an Order ID and just trying to perform the equivalent of an `UPDATE Orders SET DeliveryAddress = @p0 WHERE OrderId = @p1` is prone to tampering where a malicious user or buggy code could send an OrderID parameter that this user has no business editing, or the client allowed the update based on stale state. (Such as the edit/save was only enabled client side if the order was in particular states, but that may have changed prior to submitting)

Reading as part of an update is generally a good idea to validate the operation, check concurrency fields, and since it is a fetch by PK it should not pose any significant performance cost relative for the value it provides.